# Can't upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

I keep trying to upgrade to 14.04 from 13.10, but it comes up with the same error no matter what I disable. I spoke to a friend who is quite handy with Ubuntu and he said it might be an issue with the wheezy package. I keep removing it from the other software section of settings where the ppa's are. I then go to upgrade and there is an error message saying;

> Could not determine the upgrade
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>
> This can be caused by:
>
> - Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
> - Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
> - Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
>
> If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command '`ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`' in a terminal.

I then go into *Settings* -> *Software & Updates* -> *Other software* and wheezy is back in there.

I also had the same thing happen when I was using terminal to upgrade via the command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: `wheezy`? Are you using Debian repositories in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using certain `PPA`(for example `xorg-edgers`); you'll have to run `ppa-purge` on it before you try and upgrade (roughly this means, if you have packages installed that don't meet the dependency resolution for the upgrade this can cause it too fail).

Further if you downloaded an updated 'deb' which has a version number that matches as more current than the package that will be released within 14.04 this can cause an unmatched dependency resolution. You'll need to actual post the log file associated with the failed upgrade (it should be stored here: `/var/log/dist-upgrade/`) `main.log`, `apt.log` and `term.log` are the first ones to be looked at.

[Debugging Update Manager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingUpdateManager/)

Answer (score 0):

I always advise not to upgrade, but to do a fresh installation instead. Ubuntu installer is simple, reliable and well tested. Moreover, installation process doesn't take much time. In the other hand, upgrade can be real troublemaker, it is unreliable, almost always needs additional configuration actions after and sometimes before, and takes much more time.

So don't bother to fix upgrade problem - just avoid it by doing fresh installation. Don't forget to update your backup before. You have a backup of your files, right?

Comment: Then what about data and apps ? Like Thunderbird and all, and their saved password?

Comment: @Sharmarahul having a backup is quite obvious for me, but you are right anyway, I updated my answer with note about backup.

Comment: How well does a backup of SOFTWARE work from one version to another? Might this be a reason to actually avoid upgrades? FWIW: A fresh install from USB-memory onto a SSD takes less than ten minutes (with a fast CPU)... but then all the rest remains ;-) -- that will take a week or two.

Comment: There is no info on what hardware OP is using.